# I heard that some Moroccan Taamim and/or Piyoutim originate from the zemirot/songs of the Leviim in the Beit Hamikdash. Are there Torah Sources?

Tags: minhag, beis-hamikdash, tehilim-psalms, music, trop-cantillation

I heard that some Moroccan Taamim and/or Piyoutim originate from the  zemirot/songs of the Leviim in the Beit Hamikdash. Are there Torah Sources? I heard that the Hida wrote that there is a link between Andalous music - which some Moroccan zemirot are based upon - and zemirot from the Beit Hamikdash. I found a source that "Ledavid Baruch Hash-m Tzuri" (Tehillim 144) (that is sung by the Moroccans Motzi Shabbat) comes from the time of David Hamelech (see https://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=44842&st=&pgnum=10  ) Does anyone know of any other sources?

Comment: There are Ashkenazim who say the same thing.

Comment: There are also Yemenites who say the same thing. I think the actual answer is none of us truly know what the Levites sounded like when they sung

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Someone told me of one source for Andalous music based upon Leviim - who moved to a place called Andaluzia in Spain - in the Abarbanel - Melachim II - 25

https://www.sefaria.org/Abarbanel_on_II_Kings.25.30.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

פיר"וש שהיה גם כן משרי יון, והוא היה בחרבן בית ראשון והביא משם בני יהודה ובנימין ומשמעון ומהלוים והכהנים אשר היו בירושלם עם רב שבאו עמו ברצונם, ויביאם בדרך הים באניות למלכות ספרד ויושיבם בשני מחוזות, האחד הוא המחוז הנקרא גם היום אנדאלוז"יאה, בעיר אחת שהיה בימים ההם עיר ואם בישראל שרתי במדינות ויקראו אותה היהודים לוז"ינה וגם היום נקראת כן, ואמרו עליה הגוים שאוירה מחכים, להיות אויר הארץ ההיא זך ונקי מאד מאד, ואולי שעל זה קראוה היהודים לוזי"נה להיותה כלוז אשר בארץ ישראל מוכנת לנבואה,